# c# header needs to refresh on each request

Tags: c#, header

I have one header that would need to refresh/change per request.

I'm still kinda new to this so here is the current header:

```
request.Headers.Add("X-APP-Checksum", "f3431a80af590c726d1a6ef8812e95aea4764522");
```

And it's this part that needs to be refreshed/changed per request:

```
f3431a80af590c726d1a6ef8812e95aea4764522
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i get what you mean. I'm assuming that you want to reuse the request object and just want to change the checksum in your header.

If this is the case, maybe try "Set" instead of "Add" like this:

```
request.Headers.Set("X-APP-Checksum", checkSumVariable);
```

If you call "add" on the headers, the new checksum will be added to a collection. So after your second request, you will have 2 checksums for this key. If you use "set" instead, the checksum for the specified key will be overriden with the new checksum.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be a 20 byte hex string.
if you want to return a random checksum value on each request

```
// generate 20 random bytes
Random rnd = new Random();
Byte[] chksum = new Byte[20];
rnd.NextBytes(chksum);

// convert the byte array to a hex string representation
var strchksum = BitConverter.ToString(chksum);
// lowercase all hex characters and remove "-" characters
strchksum = strchksum.ToLower().Replace("-", "");

request.Headers.Add("X-APP-Checksum", strchksum);
```